# Free memory from viewModel from Ioc used in ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I'm currently using a ContentControl to display my views  by setting a VM and using a default data template like this :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewViewModel}">
        <views:MyView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ContainerContent}"/>
```

Here is my ContainerContent:

```
public ViewModelBase ContainerContent
{
    get
    {
        return _containerContent;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_containerContent != null)
            _containerContent.Cleanup();

        _containerContent = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ContainerContent");
    }
}
```

I currently use SimpleIoc to load ViewModel via the serviceLocator:

```
ContainerContent = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewViewModel>();
```

This works great and display correcly my View and the viewModel is assigned to the content.

Unfortunately, when I want remove the view (and the view model) from my ContentControl, my memory still used because of the release order between ViewModel, View, and SimpleIoc.The view  had reference to it  for a time (I think this timing is due to the binding after RaisePropertyCHange on the container)

I currently use a method to remove content :

```
 public void QuitCurrentContainerViewModel<T>() where T : class
        {
            ContainerContent = null;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (/*!*/SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<T>())
                {
                    SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<T>();
                }
                DispatcherHelper.RunAsync(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Do GC now");
                    GC.Collect();

                }, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
            });
        }
```

*(Using dispatcher and priority is a test)*

If I call this sometimes my memory is correctly freed, but not always.

In every cases if i force a GC.Collect from a shortcut for example, my memory is correctly managed.

What is the good way to release the memory in my case ?

Thanks!

EDIT: My bad, It works fine with that code (in my QuitCurrentContainerViewModel method i was using this check:

```
if (!SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<T>())
```

but I need this:

```
if (SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<T>())
```

This way it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code cleaned without useless calls

```
    public ViewModelBase ContainerContent
            {
                get
                {
                    return _containerContent;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_containerContent != null)
                        _containerContent.Cleanup();

                    _containerContent = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("ContainerContent");
                }
            }

            public void QuitCurrentContainerViewModel<T>() where T : class
            {
                ContainerContent = null;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<T>())
                    {
                        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<T>();
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
//TODO: Do navigation or change of content    
                });
            }
```

and here my loading of the ContentContainer

```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (!SimpleIoc.Default.ContainsCreated<MyViewModel>())
                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyViewModel>();
                ContainerViewModel.ContainerContent = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
            });
```

If anyone have a  better way to resolve this memory management , i'm fully open.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the good way to release the memory in my case ?

Use the [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) pattern for each of the objects and require it in the generic type specifier. That way a top level entity can be called directly which can subsequently clean up all its child references which adhere to the interface as well.

Remember that instances which have subscriptions, though the instance is not directly referenced in the code will become *pinned* and stay alive if they have any subscriptions which are active; keeping the garbage collector at bay.

All subscriptions must be unlinked before the instance can be garbage collected.

> If I call this sometimes my memory is correctly freed, but not always.

Are you looking at the application's private bytes? For the OS reports a full total and if the OS is not stressed, it doesn't take away memory footprint allowing the app to breathe so to speak. Private bytes will go up and down within the full allocated total.

So you may be monitoring the wrong values.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've already tried to implement Idisposable without success. It think dispose method  was not called because of the view "blocking" the instance before the refresh.


Concerning memory consumption, I use process explorer performance view with private bytes.